# Uploading a Document via the DocuSign CLM API

Tags: file-upload, docusignapi

Hi to whom it may concern,

We are attempting to upload a document to our CLM instance via the CLM API.

Steps Completed:

1. Authentication via API
2. Getting information about folder where file needs to be uploaded.

We are able to get the CreateDocumentHref from the file info and are using that as the endpoint being called.  The uri looks as follows: https://apiuploaduatna11.springcm.com/v2/d0f45cf8-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-3e32d742a3f3/folders/4b8d3adf-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-48df378a7098/documents?name=Testing.docx where the last part is the name of the file we are uploading.

The body of the post request for upload is:

```
{
    "document": "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"
}
```

The body I have added above contains the entire 64bit string for the document.  It is a word document we created just to test the upload.

The resources we have used to get this far are:

1. [DocuSign University CLM API Basics](https://dsucustomers.docusign.com/overview-of-the-docusign-clm-api/746072/scorm/35h48wr2oqnpw) - This provides the steps to upload the document but we have not got it to work following the steps.
2. [API Reference for Document Upload](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/clm-api/reference/content/content/upload/)

We are trying to accomplish this using a DocuSign Demo Account.  Will this cause an issue?

The error we receive when sending the request is:

```
{
    "Error": {
        "HttpStatusCode": 500,
        "UserMessage": "Error occurred",
        "DeveloperMessage": "Error occurred",
        "ErrorCode": 100,
        "ReferenceId": "e4d0e140-b9e5-49ec-8322-f4aaafc5ef2a"
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Document used:
[image]

Request Headers:
[image]

***This was resolved.  The POST method for uploading a document requires a binary stream and not a json body.***

Comment: Can you try a simple one line Word document and see if you get the same error?

Comment: Hi Inbar, I have added the image of the doc. It is a one line test doc.

Comment: The error I see is "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. "

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with encoding or with something else on the request that is not encoding correctly

Comment: Do you have Content-Type header?

Comment: application/x-www-form-urlencoded is the Content-Type

Comment: can you try to make it "text/plain" instead?

Comment: Do you have a link that we could possibly use to convert to base64 that would give the correct format.  I am currently using https://base64.guru/converter/encode/file for testing

Comment: You can try https://www.base64decode.org/, but I doubt that's the issue

Comment: Yip will try that now

Comment: Still getting same error; reference is: 47a4c72c-1c34-4f52-99b9-72bb686f5912

Comment: I added a screenshot of my current headers

Comment: OK, I'm trying to ask around and hope to get back to you, I don't know to explain this yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POST method for uploading a document requires a binary stream and not a JSON body.
We would update the documentation to reflect this when we get a chance.